# How to match an instantiated object to its original counterpart

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I'm after is to be able to match a copy of an item to its original counterpart. The code I'm trying to run is as shown below. I want to check if the item I have in my inventory matches the item my crafting system requires. Both items are the same, the only difference is the item in my inventory (left) is a copy of the original and the item in my crafting system is the original (right).

The code below is a part of a stringbuilder. At run-time it shows the player how many items he as of the sort that is required and how many he needs for crafting. The code works if I use the original item and not a copy of it but since I'm getting copies of items and not their original I don't know how to do this check.

I've tried matching their names but that doesn't work at all, unity throws out a null reference exception. I've been programming for about 6 - 7 months and am not very adept at it yet. I get stuck on these things a lot and would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

```
if (Icont.islots[i].item == reci.Materials[0].item)
{
    sb0.Length = 0;
    Itemslot0(Icont.islots[i].item.amount, reci.Materials[0].amount);
    iteminfo[0].text = sb0.ToString();
}
```

Things I've tried are, matching names, matching ids, using copies on both sides but all of them throws a null reference exception in my face. If you think about it that is obvious because each copy gets their own id and as such they won't match but I'm confused about why I can't match the object using their names.

Comment: If you're getting a null reference exception it's not because of comparing one string to another. It's likely because one or both of the objects from which you're trying to get the string is null. For example `Icont` is null or `Icont.islots[i]` is null. 100% there's a null in there somewhere. You can set a breakpoint and then inspect each of those items. In the immediate window, type `?Icont.islots[i]` to see if that's null. If it's not, type `?Icont.islots[i].item` and see if that's null. It's in there.

Comment: Sorry Scott, I didn't quite get what you meant, I tried throwing out a Debug.Log(?Icont.islots[i].item) but this didn't work so I tried to just write it ?Icont.islots[i].item and below that use a Debug.break();  

since none of these work I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong. Adding a "?" inside a debug.log gives me a "Identifier expected error message" adding it to the if statement gives "Invalid expression Term" error message.

Comment: It needs to be in the immediate window. Debug > Windows > Immediate. That lets you evaluate properties and variables.

Comment: Ah, I see. This should come in handy, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in this line: `if (Icont.islots[i].item == reci.Materials[0].item)`

Because the items your are comparing are [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) (I assume they are 'classes') then your use of the default `==` operator will do a reference equality check (unless you overload it, which it seems you haven't).

What that means is the `==` will check to see if the two items are a reference to the same object in memory. This is why you see the desired behaviour when they are, and the undesired behaviour when one is simply a clone of the other.

There are a multitude of ways you can solve this issue; You could change the item type to be a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) (a `Struct`), you could overload the `==` operator, you could use a custom equality comparison and the list goes on.

What I would personally do is create a custom equality comparison function which essentially says "Item 1 is equal to Item 2 if *these* properties are the same".

A small example would be:

```
public static bool IsEqualTo(this Item thisItem, Item otherItem)
{
    if (thisItem is null) return otherItem is null;
    else if (otherItem is null) return thisItem is null;

    return thisItem.property1 == otherItem.property1
        && thisItem.property2 == otherItem.property2
        && thisItem.property3 == otherItem.property3;
}
```

Then simply change

```
if (Icont.islots[i].item == reci.Materials[0].item)
```

to

```
if (Icont.islots[i].item.IsEqualTo(reci.Materials[0].item))
```

This approach gives you control over how to define equality. For example you might say that every different item in your game has some `Id` property that is unique to that item type. If that is the case, then your `IsEqualTo()` method simply needs to return whether or not both objects have the same Id.

EDIT: As @ScottHannen said in the comments, if you are getting a `NullReferenceException` then it means that one of the items you are referencing has not actually been initialised. Make sure that every object and property you need on both items are actually initialised.

Comment: Wow, ok. Thanks for the quick response. I Implemented a custom equality function with only one property which was the name of the objects. This worked splendidly, Thanks a lot Darren :D. Though to be frank all this overloading operators went over my head. The examples on the Microsoft docs didn't help much either. How often do people use overloaded operators? I haven't seen anyone do it so far.

Comment: No problem! Overloaded operators are a fairly common thing in Desktop & Web Applications though perhaps not so much in Unity Game Development. I don't have any figures to back that up, just my suspicion. They can be very useful when you find yourself having multiple ways to compare objects but you also want your comparisons to have custom rules. For example you might create a custom type which represents some sort of number, you would likely then overload the `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>` operators and so on because there are multiple ways to compare them.